# 3-vote close - how's it going?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-reopen, vote-to-close

### UPDATE: While the testing period has ended, this change has been well-received by the community so we have opted to not reset the votes needed to close/reopen to 5 while we look at data.

Please let me know if you have any concerns about this change in the planned process or if you feel the number of votes should be changed back at least temporarily. I'll be back in a few weeks with the results of the project.

---

Part of understanding the impact of three-vote closure is to understand what impact it's having on y'all. I'd like to ask anyone who feels up to it to **write an answer to this question** and to tell us about your experience over the past few weeks.

The sorts of things I'm interested in knowing (feel free to address all or none or add your own) -

- Did this help?
- Did it hurt?
- Did it make you more interested in close/reopen reviewing? Less?

  - Are there things other than 3-vote close impacting your interest in reviewing?
- If you can't vote but do flag, did this make you more/less likely to flag?
- Would you prefer to go back to 5?
- Should it be permanent?
- What would you like me to look into when it comes to analyzing the data from the test?
- Were there any side-effects (good or bad) that you want me to be aware of?

These are merely prompts, so feel free to add anything I'm missing that you think is worth saying. This is focused on how you're feeling about it and what data you want me to look at, so don't feel like you need to analyze the data over the last 30 days - though you're welcome to if that's how you figure out what you feel.

If you have any outstanding questions, also feel welcome to ask them here.

The test will run until about Monday the 21st of June, at which point we'll be resetting the votes to close up to 5 while I review the responses here and dig into the data that we've been collecting.

Comment: Just adding a link to the post on Meta SE with the test results: [Three-vote close/reopen test - results](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370373).

Answer (score 11):

In sequence:

- Did this help?  Kind of.  I still see the diamond moderators closing things quicker than the community which gets to your point about there being a bigger problem.
- Did it hurt?  Doubt that it did.
- Did it make you more interested in close/reopen reviewing? Less?  I don't participate in the queues but if nothing else I've been more interested in closing questions as of late.
- Would you prefer to go back to 5?  No!
- Should it be permanent? Yes!
- What would you like me to look into when it comes to analyzing the data from the test?

  - How many closures were done by the community as opposed to mods?
  - How many close votes were cast per day?
- Were there any side-effects (good or bad) that you want me to be aware of?  An active count of how many active curators there are is going to be needed.

Answer (score 8):

*This answer was written by a mod at the time of writing, so it might have some bias. That said...*

---

- **Did this help?**
  Kind of. I noticed a few questions were closed successfully without mod's intervention, so it's certainly an improvement.
- **Did it hurt?**
  I saw no questions were incorrectly closed ([1 (now-deleted) question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/63997/civilization-type-anime-like-overlord-and-slime) was almost closed with a different reason than what I assume should be closed), so it didn't hurt (yet).
- **Did it make you more interested in close/reopen reviewing? Less?**
  No effect. I see a red dot, I click.

  - **Are there things other than 3-vote close impacting your interest in reviewing?**
    I guess we all know that we still have barely enough active users with close votes privilege.
- **If you can't vote but do flag, did this make you more/less likely to flag?**
  Not applicable for mods.
- **Would you prefer to go back to 5?**
  Nope!
- **Should it be permanent?**
  Yes, please.
- **What would you like me to look into when it comes to analyzing the data from the test?**

  - In addition to the close votes, how many close *flags* were cast?
  - If those close flags were actually close votes, how many additional questions would be closed without mod's intervention?
- **Were there any side-effects (good or bad) that you want me to be aware of?**
  As of now, not really. We still have not enough active users with close votes privilege to make this a problem, and most users generally flag/vote reasonably.